# Youtube feed api json not give tags :(

Tags: parsing, youtube, tags, json-c

I want parse these tags. Earlier, a few months ago, he gave me a tags, but now will not be. My query looks like:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=MYAYTHOR&v=2&alt=jsonc

Answer (score 0):

According to Youtube API news they removed tags from feed for everyone except uploader
See details here http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html